# How to select "OK" Button from Android Keyboard in Appium

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am trying to click on "Ok" Button i.e. tick mark in Android device, but its happening, since keypad has not any xpath value.
Can someone please help me on this?
[image]

Comment: what are you using UIAutomator or AppiumInspector ? share the snap when you move your cursor on this

Comment: AppiumInspector @pankajmishra

Comment: can you share the screenshot of AppiumInspector when you click this particular button?

Answer (score 0):

Key presses on appium are done by 
`driver.press_keycode(code)`

[All  required codes can be found here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

- 66 - `KEYCODE_ENTER`

So in your case, 
final code would be like,

`driver.press_keycode(66)`